# How to install react-paystack in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to install react-paystack and I am getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: myfapp@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-paystack@3.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-paystack
npm ERR!   react-paystack@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Jeffrey Matthew\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jeffrey Matthew\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-12T05_04_04_535Z-debug.log
```

Any solutions, please?

Comment: try deleting the node_modules folder and install again

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is clear. Installed `react` version is 17.0.2 where as `react-paystack 3.0.4` requires older version (16.x).

As current `react-paystack` only works on `react` 16.x, I think the only way is to create react project with 16.x version and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You might have another node_modules folder or package.json file in a parent folder.